# jQuery UI - slider + progressbar effect

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking to build a control that's a combination of the jquery ui [progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) and [slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#default). What I really need is exactly like the [range slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range), except that the max shouldn't have a handle and shouldn't be movable by the user. I want to implement something like a buffered playback control, where the 'fill' is the max amount buffered and the slider handle shows the current position.

Before I go mess with the slider code to do this, I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on how I could implement this without any custom changes. One idea that comes to mind, but I don't know how to implement, is to superimpose a [range with fixed minimum slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin) (and hidden handle) on top of a regular slider. I can put these side-by-size or above/below but I don't know HTML/CSS well enough to pull off the 'superimpose' effect. Any ideas on how to do this would help too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've prepared a small patch to the slider widget for constraints. Here's a demo of the behavior I believe you're looking for:

http://devsandbox.nfshost.com/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/demos/slider/constraints.html

Here's the patched file:

http://devsandbox.nfshost.com/js/jquery-ui/development-bundle/ui/ui.slider.js

Comment: you're awesome. I wish I could upvote this more than once. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm, uh, finding myself somewhat motivated by rep. :D

(Someone should start a development firm that just reduces everything to Stack Overflow questions.)

Comment: FYI, the jQuery UI project has rejected the patch. "You can use progressbar and slider on the same element and get the visual feedback, then you would just need to enforce the constraints using the slide event."